# Have I found a counterexample in this question?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \,$ is a function with $x_0 \in \overline{X}   \,\setminus \partial(\overline{X}) $ such that :

$$\exists \,\,\,\,f'_-(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0},$$

$$\exists \,\,\,\,f'_+(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
 but with possibly $f'_-(x_0) \not= f'_+(x_0)$,  does this still imply continuity of $f$ ?

if so then why can I have a function such as $$f(x) =       \begin{cases}       3x \, , \text{  if}  \,\,\, x<x_0 \\       10x+1 \, ,\text{  if}  \,\,\, x=x_0 \\       -2x \, , \text{  if}  \,\,\, x>x_0       \end{cases} $$
that does have $f'_-(x_0)=3$ and $f'_+(x_0)=-2$ but is not continuous, does that mean that only the existence of the left and right side derivatives on a point do not guarantee that $f $ is continuous at $x_0$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven’t found the limits right.  I will take the example of $x_0=0$. There $$f’^+=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{2x-1}{x}   =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} 2 - \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$$ and 
$$f’^-=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{3x-1}{x}   =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} 3 - \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$$

Actually, continuity is implied because $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}f(x) = f(x_0)$ since the two one-sided limits of your question exist (and are finite).

Comment: I think you cannot use the value of the function at point $x_0$ to calculate the limit in general.

Comment: @FelipeDilho What do you mean? That is exactly the definition of these two limits. Perhaps you are confusing with using the function value of f to compute the limits of f itself (as opposed to the derivative limits which I have here).

Comment: Yes you are right i got confused when i asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the limits exist, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}(x-x_0)+f(x_0)\right)=f(x_0)
$$
and similarly for the limit from the left.

You are confusing
$$
f'_+(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$
with
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)
$$
which can be different.